# swift 2 how to remove empty rows in a tableview in a viewcontroller

Tags: swift, swift2, tableview

Is there a way to reset tableview height so that no empty rows are showed. For an example, a tableview displays 3 rows but there is only one row having real data. I'd like the tableview shrinks it size so there is only one row display

Comment: You should post the code for your tableview's data source and delegate methods. The answer will depend on how you have those methods set up.

Comment: Since I don't know how to do it so there are no code written yet

Answer (score 2):

I guess you have a View Controller like this

```
class Controller: UITableViewController {

    private var data: [String?] = ["One", nil, "Three", nil, nil]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellID")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

Since your model (`data` in my example) contains `nil` values you are getting a table view like this

> 1. One
> 2. _
> 3. Three
> 4. _
> 5. _

### Removing the empty rows

Now you want instead a table view like this right?

> 1. One
> 2. Three

### Filtering your model

Since the UI (the table view) is just a representation of your model you need to **change your model**.

It's pretty easy

```
class Controller: UITableViewController {

    private var data: [String?] = ["One", nil, "Three", nil, nil]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellID")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        data = data.filter { $0 != nil }
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

As you can see, inside `viewDidLoad()` I removed the bill values from the `data` array. Now you'll get only cells for real values.

Comment: No, that is not the case. My case is that in the storyboard, there are about 6 rows, and in the real world, there are only 2 rows. so when the app runs, it leaves 4 empty rows. What I like to do is to remove these 4 empty rows and shrink the tableview height to the end of second row.

Comment: @user584819: so in Storyboard you did set `Content = Static Cells` for your tableview, right?

Comment: No. it is a dynamic cells

Comment: @user584819: In your previous comments you said `in the storyboard, there are about 6 rows`. But now you say that it has `dynamic cells`. How is this possible? Is the number of the rows in your table defined in Storyboard o via code?

Comment: Just an example. Using dynamic cells, tableview has size of w=280, h=500. But when data are populated into the tableview, there are only 2 rows about h=80 long. How do I shrink the tableview height from 500 to 80 so there is no empty space after the last row.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need remove the empty data before execute `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int`.

//EDITED

I give you this possible solution, maybe there are more ways to do it, you can try with this.

```
class MyViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    private var realHeight = 0
    private var data : [String] = []

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MyCellID")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.row]

        self.realHeight += self.tableView.rowHeight //Increase real height value.

        return cell
    }

    func loadData() { //This function reload the data

        self.realHeight = 0
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        //Update tableViewHeight here, use self.realHeight. You can use constraints or update directly the frame.

    }

}
```

The solution is have a counter that represents the sum of all visibles rows height. e.g If you have **n** cells then your height will be `self.tableView.rowHeight` * **n**, then you ever will have an effective height.

I recommend you to create a constraint for the table height and when the cells change, you only need change the constant of the constraint, is more easy than change the frame.

Comment: No, that is not the case. My case is that in the storyboard, there are about 6 rows, and in the real world, there are only 2 rows. so when the app runs, it leaves 4 empty rows. What I like to do is to remove these 4 empty rows and shrink the tableview height to the end of second row.

Comment: Hi @user584819, I don't understand correctly you :( Can you provide me some code?

Comment: I cannot because I don't know what to do. Think of a simple example. In side of UIViewController in a storyboard, you add a uitableview with size w=280 and h=500. In the code, you only populate 2 row/cell data so left a lot of empty space in the tableview. What I'd like to do is to shrink the size to something like h=100 which is the end of second row. How do I do that?

Comment: @user584819 I understand now! I will edit my answer.